# How to react properly on fetched data in spinejs

Tags: ajax, coffeescript, spine.js

I've set up a small spinejs application with an api as backend for storing new data und serving already saved data.
When my app is loading I'm doing the following:

```
require('lib/setup')

Spine = require('spine')
Posts = require('controllers/posts')
Post = require('models/post')

class App extends Spine.Controller
  constructor: ->
  super

  @log("App up and running :)")

  @posts = new Posts
  Post.fetch()

  #defining starting point of application
  @routes
    '/': ->
       @posts.main.show_all.active()

  Spine.Route.setup()

  @html @posts.active()

module.exports = App
```

My target is to display the latest 5 posts when visiting the index page.
Fetching the data works fine but I'm only able to see the data when I revisit the index page via a ink.
What must I do to see the posts just after they have been loaded!?
I've already red something that I have to react on the refresh event. But right now I don't know where I should add the listener and what it must do.
Home someone can give me a hint.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you have to bind a handler to the refresh event for your Post model

```
Post.fetch()
Post.bind 'refresh', @onPostsFetched
```

where onPostsFetched is a method of your controller

```
onPostsFetched: ->
  @posts = Post.all()
```

hope this helps

Comment: thanks got it working now :) I've added the following function: ``onPostsFetched: =>
    @posts.main.show_all.active()``

Comment: When exactly does the 'refresh' action get called? Good answer, btw.